# Trying to find the governor limit that would apply to my particular flow

Tags: governorlimits, emailmessage

I have a app installed in an org that lets the company send bulk emails via Sendgrid API (not via Salesforce). The leads and contacts get an EmailMessage record added, whith the relatedTo.Id being a campaign.

What I need to do is update the campaign status based on that EmailMessage record being added to the Lead or Contact.

This is a pretty simple flow or trigger, but considering the volume of these emails that go out (about 7k per hour), and the fact that the EmailMessage records are added synchronously, means that's how many flow interviews would occur.

The campaign member status needs to be updated in near real-time, so a scheduled batch update would't work either.

Any idea what limits the org would hit first?

Answer (score 0):

Governor limits are almost always caused by configuration or programming that's running inefficiently, and is very circumstantial. An efficiently designed package paired with an org that has conscientious configuration and automation shouldn't run into any limits. Which limits you might run into would depend on how heavily customized and automated your org is, and may also be affected by the number of active concurrent users. If you're really concerned there could be problems, you can always arrange for a [Performance Test](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387059&type=1).

Comment: There are other flavours of limit that could be encountered, such as async per day (possibly at play here) or API limits (probably not relevant here).

Comment: Thanks - any recommendation on how I can solution this with the least risk?